# CSS files hosted by GitHub not updated after edit

Tags: blogger, github-pages

I have upload some **css** and **js** files to **GitHub** repository and I have link them with a **Google Blog** using **RawGit** server.

```
<link href='https://cdn.rawgit.com/username/repo/tag/file.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
```

It works but, my problem is when I make code changes to any of these files. Is there any special thing that I have to do after edit a file so to keep the changes? Because after I edit a css file for example and use my browser to check it, it looks like nothing changed, like it haven't updated!!!

Please note that I am totally new on this GitHub stuff!!!

Comment: have you tried to clear all the cached files? or open in incognito mode?

Comment: Yes, nothing!!!

Comment: A repository url can be useful to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rawgit is not part of GitHub.

Its a different website that uses your github files.

As I read in RawGit

> https://cdn.rawgit.com/

Its for Production environment. (has a cache)

If you are pushing changes and you want to see it as soon as you push change the url to be just

> https://rawgit.com/

please read the https://pages.github.com/ maybe you don't need another service and you could live just with GitHub.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "maybe you don't need another service"? Is there any other way to link my css and js files from GitHub to Google blog without rawgit?

Comment: I have done this, I have create a page for test, but I can't understand how can this help me to link a css or js file to a Google Blog!!! Except if you mean to make my page from the start in GitHub pages lol...

Comment: You could have a link like:
https://username.github.io/repo/tag/file.css

Comment: Please read here: 
https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-github-pages/#usage-limits